# What does *-1 means?

Tags: delphi

I don't know how to find keyword for this (*-) in Google, and I don't know what is name. So I ask here.

Sample code :

```
StartDate:=IncMinute(FinishDate,TotalMinutes*-1);
```

What is `TotalMinutes*-1` if I write in 'normal' syntax ?

Comment: It's (number x -1) ... (eg. 22 x -1 = -22).

Comment: It's use of the basic math operators (+ for add, - for subtraction, * for multiplication, and either div for integer division or / for floating point division. The `-1` is using the unary minus, indicating that it operates on one value (so it means in thsi case -1. So `TotalMinuts * -1` means *multiply TotalMinutes by -1* This [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_operators.htm) might help.

Comment: `StartDate := IncMinute(FinishDate, -TotalMinutes);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is multiplying `TotalMinutes` by -1... IOW, it looks like it is decrementing the Minutes.

Write it like this: `TotalMinute * -1` and it is more clear. The `*` is the multiplication operator and the `-` is the unary minus operator.

Comment: Or, more simply `-TotalMinute`

Comment: Of course. I was merely answering the question asked.

Comment: So if    
`TotalMinute*-1 { is just like --> }  
TotalMinute := TotalMinute * (-1)` ?

Comment: To be exact: `TotalMinute*-1` is the same as `TotalMinute * (-1)`.